# Reversing the order of displayed data from a SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

My website (thanks to help from many of you here on SO) is set up to display a fixed number of updates (52) where each Friday, one rotates out, and a new one rotates in. The 52 updates are displayed 4 per page across 13 pages. It works perfectly.

However, the new update appears at the END of the displayed updates. I would like the new update to be the first one people will see.

Here is my query:

```
$conn = dbConnect('query');
$updates = "SELECT update_id, update_title, update_desc, path
    FROM updates
    WHERE flag_live = ?
    ORDER BY update_id DESC
    LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($updates);
$stmt->bind_param('sii', $uLive, $offset, $limit);
$stmt->bind_result($uId, $uTitle, $uDesc, $uPath);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

I want the items to display in reverse order as they currently do. If I change the `ORDER BY` from `DESC` to `ASC` it picks a different set of data which I do not want. Thus, from my research I have seen that either `array_reverse()` or `rsort` would do the trick. I need to know what syntax is correct to use `array_reverse()` properly here.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php what you not understand here ?

Comment: @eicto I have read through that already. The PHP manual is something that rarely makes sense to me, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: What's so hard to understand about `$reversed = array_reverse($input);` ?

Comment: @Patashu Well, since I am still relatively new to PHP, a LOT of it is hard to understand. Let me try a different approach: The basic array_reverse() function makes sense...but I'm unsure what part ot parts of my query above should go inside it.

Comment: `array_reverse` reverses an array, so you want to get an array of the rows the query returned and pass it to `array_reverse`.

Comment: @Patashu I understand that. I need help with the code. I'm still new to prepared statements, so I do not know what to put inside `array_reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$results = array_reverse( $results );
```

The next part can be done a few different ways so it really depends on how you are going to use the results and paginate them.

You could use a `for` loop: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php
Or `foreach`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: What happens with that code is I get one update per page and not the 4 I get currently.

Comment: Notice that `fetchAll()` is being used. You may have to adjust the way you show the "updates" because `stmt->fetchAll()` gets all of the results at once.

Comment: yeah, actually `fetchAll()` bombed the page so I removed the `All` part which led to the result mentioned above. This is a headbanger for me for sure.

Comment: You have to get them all so that PHP can reverse them. You'll probably have to change the way the "updates" are shown to account for it. I'm guessing, but you're probably using something like `while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() )` which won't work.

Comment: I am actually using a do/while loop to limit the display to 4 per page: `do {...` `while ($stmt->fetch());`. So if I understand you correctly, this would work bang on if I was showing all 52 updates on one page, but since I paginate the result set, I'm going to be unable to do this?

Comment: Maybe if we saw your `do-while` loop then it will make a little more sense.

Comment: I'm familiar with loop structure, but thanks for the links above. The do/while is just outputting the data relevant to each of the four updates displayed per page.

Comment: If that's the case then you can use a `foreach` loop instead of the `do-while` loop.

Comment: Well, from what I understand, the only way to make `array_reverse` work is to fetch the entire result set. My query, shown above, only grabs four results of the 52 at one time. So, if I have to `fetchAll`, then I'll have to re-write the navigation/pagination, or hope to find an alternative method. I'm realizing now the limit here is selecting a subset of records and not all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get along well with PHP, but something like this?

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$results = array_reverse( $results );
foreach ($results as $row)
{
  /* $row will contain each row in the reversed array one at a time. do your usual process-one-row logic here */
}
```

Btw, when you don't know what a PHP function returns when you call it, there is a very useful debugging function, var_dump. You can call it on anything and it'll print what it's composed of, recursively.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Thank you for that! I think JDavis' answer below is telling me that I can't do what I want as I am breaking up the 52 updates into 13 pages of 4 each.

Comment: Do the select query, then do a for loop like for `($i = 0+pagenumber*4; $i < 4+pagenumber*4; ++$i)` ?

Comment: I'm just not getting my head wrapped around this one, but I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of headbanging, I was able to accomplish this task, though not in a manner that I had considered when I posted this question. What I ended up doing was writing a subquery which allowed me to reverse the order of the updates displayed on each page, and as you'll know, this only reverses the order of the four updates visible on the page, NOT the overall order of the 52 chosen (see original question).

The next step was to 'reverse' my pagination system...no small task...rewriting logic, testing code, etc. So by reversing things with a subquery and reversing my pagination, I achieved my goal.

All of your suggestions her helped with the final outcome, though not in a way expected. I apologize in advance if this is not as concise as answering my own question should be.